# Sidebar pushed below content in an individual post (WordPress)

Tags: css, wordpress, post, sidebar

Everything is fine on the main page, but when I go into any individual post, the side bar is getting pushed off and showing up right down the button of the page (below the comments).

It's pretty obvious that there is some kind of sizing/width issue and I've played around with a lot of the widths in firebug but just can't seem to find where it's going wrong.

I'm new yo wordpress so clear steps to solve this problem are high appreciated

Thanks in advance for any help!

Link to single post: http://www.misslittletouch.com/2013/08/27/temporada-deco/E

Comment: Check the php includes on both of the pages, see if they are the same.

Comment: I've just solved it.
Downloaded this plugin that fixed everything alone.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/twenty-eleven-theme-extensions/installation/

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved it.
Downloaded this plugin that fixed everything alone.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/twenty-eleven-theme-extensions/installation/